# Change View via JQuery POST while passing model data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an internal testing site for our search index, and I was looking to have the page be redirected to a search results page after all of the data has been entered and submitted on the search query page. I have also never implemented a website (beyond just basic HTML) until I received this assignment. Regardless, I've made good progress (with some frustrating roadblocks) but this one seems to be impossible given the tools that I have now, although it shouldn't be.

I have an array of complex objects (`QueryDataModel`) that I pass to the controller, since it tells the server what searches to run where and with what parameters. Those parameters and server data are gathered by Javascript from the forms on the page. I don't have any problems `$.ajax` posting that data, but the issue is that I can't immediately redirect the user to the new page if I use `$.ajax`.

I then found that I could use a non-AJAX POST to immediately redirect the user, but it seems like it's impossible for me to pass parameters this complex that way; there isn't any well-supported function in jQuery to perform a non-AJAX POST. The popular way seems to be to set up a fake form, and then populate its inputs with the parameters you want to pass, which doesn't seem to work with the objects I have.

Right now I have it set up to go to a redirecting action, since I read the description for RedirectToAction on MSDN and thought it would actually force the browser to change pages... alas, it did not.

So, how would I pass an array of complex objects to the controller to be used as a model for a new view, and then redirect the user to that new view?

Controller actions:

```
public ActionResult Results()
    {
        ViewData["MrSIXGTs"] = MvcApplication.MrSixGts;
        ViewData["MrSIXs"] = MvcApplication.MrSixs;
        return View(MixedSearch(TempData["qdm"] as QueryDataModel[]));
    }

    public ActionResult RedirectResults(QueryDataModel[] qd)
    {
        TempData["qdm"] = qd;
        return RedirectToAction("Results", "Search");
    }
```

Relevant Javascript (commented out methods I've already tried included):

```
var qdm = [];
    $('#search-list > .search-form').each(function() {
        var formwrapper = this;
        var servs = [];
        var c = 0;
        $('#' + $(formwrapper).attr('id') + ' > .server-checkbox:checked').each(function () {
            servs.push($(this).attr('name'));
            c++;
        });
        $('#' + $(formwrapper).attr('id') + ' > .form-wrapper > form').each(function() { // only one iteration; not really a loop
            var z = new QueryDataModel($(this).parent().attr('id'), servs, $(this).serializeArray(), {});
            qdm.push(z);
        });
    });
//$.doPost('/Search/RedirectResults', { qd: qdm }); // fake form function
    var str = $.param(qdm);
    alert(str);
    document.location = baseUrl + '/Search/RedirectResults' + '?' + str; // doesn't serialize properly due to the complexity
    /*
    $.ajax({ // doesn't redirect the user
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: '/Search/RedirectResults',
            data: $.toJSON(qdm),
            success: function () {
                //alert(baseUrl + '/Search/Results');
                //window.location.href = baseUrl + '/Search/Results';
            },
            error: function(e, t, n) {
                alert(t + ": " + n);
            }
    });*/
function QueryDataModel(sn, serv, fd, fc) {
    this.SearchName = sn;
    this.Servers = serv;
    this.InputParams = fc;
    this.FormData = $.toJSON(fd); // easier to deserialize this stuff server-side into InputParams
}
```

Comment: why not just use a form that posts the fields to your controller and handle the data there? if you are trying to immediately redirect there is no need to use ajax at all.

Comment: It's kind of a complicated page. I decided to make it such that I can add and remove forms from the page dynamically. There's a submit button for each individual search form, and a submit all button. I'm testing the submit all button, here, so I have to intercept all the form data, combine it into one model, and send it to the controller.

Comment: can submit a form with one field that is nothing but json stringified object. That said though, showing a loading indicator and redirect in ajax success isn't horrible either

Comment: @charlietfl Whew... sometimes I feel like there's too many things I need to check over when I'm developing this hilariously complicated website. I feel like I should have gotten that one, but I didn't. I had actually come close if you check the comments (`$.doPost` does exactly what you described, but I used `{qd: qdm}` instead of `{qd: JSON.stringify(qdm)}`) Please post this as an answer so I can give you your due.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest approach might be to post a simple one input form  where you JSON.stringify your big object as the value